# In Blueberry Garden, how does eating a blueberry affect you?

Tags: blueberry-garden

So, some of the fruits and things that you can eat are pretty easy to figure out.  But the first fruit you come to, the blueberry, just turns you bluish.  What else does it do?  I Googled around a bit for reviews, but they were careful about spoilers or were straight-up "walkthroughs" which I avoided.

Comment: Added the `blueberry-garden` tag for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this forum post](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=10307882&postcount=8), blueberries let you fly higher.

Comment: Sweet...funny that I didn't find that.  Thanks.